# Automatically logon into Spring Security secured webapp based on username from OS

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

I have come around some web applications which automatically logon a user based on the user currently logged on to the OS. I have examples which work in IE/Win and Chrome/Win/Linux.

In IE the setting can be controller with the "User authentication" parameters: [image: Screenshot of IE settings dialog]

Chrome seems to do it automatically without any possible configuration options.

**My current setup:**

I use Spring Security 3.2.5 with the `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` which works perfectly, but still requires the user to enter username and password.

My container is Tomcat 7 running on JRE 1.7.0_65.

**Now to the question:**

Can I configure Spring Security's `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` to use the currently logged in user?

Or, optionally, create a `Filter` or something alike to get the currently logged user and do the login to the webapp myself programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need Kerberos (SPNEGO) in order to perform a single sign on.

See https://github.com/kwart/spnego-demo and http://server.dzone.com/articles/spnego-authentication-jboss